# Use bash to extract data between two regular expressions while keeping the formatting

Tags: bash, awk

but I have a question about a small piece of code using the awk command. I have not found an answer/solution anywhere.

I am trying to parse an output file and extract all data between the 1st expression (including) `ATOMIC` and 2nd expression (excluding) `Bond`. This data is to be sent to a new file `$1_geom`. So far I have the following:

```
`awk '/ATOMIC/{flag=1;next}/Bond lengths in Bohr/{flag=0}flag' $1` >> $1_geom
```

This script will extract the correct data for me, but there are 2 problems:

1. The line `ATOMIC`is not extracted with the data
2. The data is extracted and appended to a single line. I want the data to retain the formatting from the parsed file (5 columns, variable amount of lines). Please see attachment to see a visual. [Visual Example Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akxMV.jpg). Is there a different way to append data (other than >>) so that I can keep formatting?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why is the command in backticks? `\``

Answer (score 0):

The `next` is causing the first match to be skipped; take it out if you don't want that.

The backticks by themselves are a shell syntax error (unless your Awk script happens to produce valid shell commands). I'm guessing you have a [useless `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) or something like that in your actual script which disarms the error, but instead produces the symptoms you describe.

Comment: Your screen shot seems to confirm my guess. Please don't post images when what you actually want to show is text.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This was part of the code in a csh script and I did have an "echo" in front of this line. Removing the "echo" makes it work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This was part of a code in a csh script and I did have an "echo" in front of this line. Removing the "echo" makes it work perfectly and addresses the 2 questions that I had.

Comment: As an aside, you'll thank yourself many times for switching to a sane shell from `csh`. [tchrist's old FAQ](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot) has all the dirt.